# What is exactly Swift and Obejctive-C's compatibility about?

Tags: objective-c, swift

They said that those languages are compatible, but what exactly does it mean?

Can I for example make a .h file containing a class, include it into my Swift code and create an object (in Swift) of this Obj-C class?

That's just what I thought, but it doesn't seem possible... Can somebody explain it to me, please :)?

Comment: Watch the WWDC videos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a 'bridging header' that exports your Objective-C classes for use in Swift. There's a ton of documentation on this available for free: https://itunes.apple.com/us/book/using-swift-cocoa-objective/id888894773?mt=11

Comment: If you don't feel like reading it in iBooks, this doc is also available on the web at [developer.apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216) and in the Xcode 6 documentation viewer (search for "swift" to find it and several other books and sample code projects).

Comment: There's also two excellent videos on this from WWDC this year: "Integrating Swift with Objective C" and "Swift Interoperability in Depth".